# Work-around for Tooltip in QuantilePlot?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, tooltip, workaround

I can use Tooltip to show the value of each element in a ListPlot:

```
ListPlot[Table[Tooltip[a = Random[], a], {i, 1, 100}]]
```

but applied to QuantilePlot,

```
QuantilePlot[Table[Tooltip[a = Random[], a], {i, 1, 100}]]
```

one gets a error message

> QuantilePlot::ldata: 0.3164278757335126` is not a valid dataset, distribution, or a valid list of datasets and distributions.

and the return is not a plot but

> ```
> QuantilePlot[{<numbers with tooltip when hovered over by mouse>}]
> ```

How can I work around this? I think it's a bug.

Answer (score 2):

What you are encountering is not a bug. You are misinterpreting the `QuantilePlot` documentation. `Tooltip` can only be applied to the data as a whole, not to individual elements of the data (unless you do some post-processing of the plot as kuba suggests).

Thus

```
SeedRandom[42]; QuantilePlot[Tooltip @ RandomReal[1., 100]]
```

works fine and gives

[image: plot]

Comment: The values shown in the `Tooltip` are consistent with `Dataset@Association@
  Thread[{"max", "75%", "median", "25%", "min"} -> 
    Quantile[data, Range[1, 0, -1/4]]]` but the values differ from those provided by `Quartiles[data]` or `Median[data]`. It is not clear why the `Quantile` method is used rather than the "Quartile` method since quartiles are being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 100]

QuantilePlot[data] /. Point[pos_] :> (Tooltip[Point[#], #] & /@ pos)
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you!

Comment: @qwerty I'm glad it fits your needs. Please take a [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)